# Issue with Impromptu in C#

Tags: c#, impromptu-interface

I am using Impromptu in C# and I have the following situation.

This is my class that I am populating:

```
public class FinalDecisionInformation
{
  public int PersonNo { get; set; }
  public int OrdNo { get; set; }
  public int OrdLineNo { get; set; }
  public int OrdStatus { get; set; }
}
```

This is the definition of the interface IFinalDecisionEvaluate:

```
public interface IFinalDecisionEvaluate
{
  List<FinalDecisionInformation> FinalDecisionList { get; set; }
}
```

My code is currently looking like this:

```
List<FinalDecisionInformation> finalDecision = (List<FinalDecisionInformation>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

var finalDecisionSend = Impromptu.ActLike<IFinalDecisionEvaluate>(finalDecision);
```

This code is throwing the following error:

```
((ActLike_IFinalDecisionEvaluate_f627852407d342cb8e77c394c0b2791f)finalDecisionSend).FinalDecisionList = '((ActLike_IFinalDecisionEvaluate_f627852407d342cb8e77c394c0b2791f)finalDecisionSend).FinalDecisionList' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'
```

So essentially, I need to simply map my list object to the interface. Can anyone please assist with this error? I cannot figure out where the mismatch is.

Thanks!

Comment: i m not sure, but can you try this? `List<FinalDecisionInformation> finalDecision = serializer.Deserialize<FinalDecisionInformation>(stringReader)`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I figured it out. I needed to create a proxy object with the field name specified in the interface:

```
var finalDecisionList = new { FinalDecisionList = finalDecision };
var finalDecisionSend = Impromptu.ActLike<IFinalDecisionEvaluate>(finalDecisionList);
```

That seems to work. So we learn!